# GHCi on windows 10 exits right after opened

Tags: windows, ghci

I have downloaded the latest version [Haskell Platform](https://www.haskell.org/platform/windows.html) to my Windows 10 machine. Run the installer, clicked through the wizard, and was told that everything was OK.

Icon for GHCi appeared in the start menu.

Bu when I click on it, it opens up a small console-looking window (telling me it version number, and to 'click :? for help'), and then **exits immediately** (in  a split-second).

What could be the cause of this behaviour, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I'd comment this, but I don't have enough rep. Sorry!

The problem is more likely with your system or the installation than the program. Did you run the SHA-256 hash to make sure that your downloads were not corrupted? The problem could also be an anti-virus program; check and see if you can add GHCi to its list of allowed programs. You may want to test WinGHCi to see if you have the same problem.

Comment: If the download was corrupt, the installer would already not have worked.

Comment: Oops, that's probably right. I wonder if he would be able to run GHC in the command prompt.